# Which sankhya scriptures were taught to buddha?

Tags: buddha, scripture, children

From wikipedia :
Alara Kalama (Pāḷi & Sanskrit Āḷāra Kālāma/ Arāḍa Kālāma]), was a hermit and a teacher of SamkhyaHe was the first teacher of Gautama Buddha.

I want to know  ***which scriptures of samkhya philosophy were taught to buddha?***

Also was Buddha told characters of mahabharat /ramayan . Is it mentioned anywhere?

Comment: Historically I don't think this can be known, but it's reasonable to assume that he was well versed in the Hindu ideas of his day.

Comment: @Cdn_Dev Is it mentioned in any buddhist scriptures? History stack exchange suggested to ask me here 

Comment: Ramayana is estimated to have been written around 400 BC-200 BC while Mahabharata is estimated to be written between 400 BC-400 AD. From this it can be argued that both were written at least centuries after Buddha's Mahaparinirvana. Therefore, it does not seem possible that Buddha could be told of characters from the two epics.

Comment: @HomagetoManjushri first of all datings has problems because panini of 5 th century BC in asthadhyayi sutra 6.2.38 mentions mahabharat and mahabharat has many references from Ramayana. Also they have oral transmissions all over India. So, maybe buddha could know them by oral transmissions. Jataka tales also have few references

Comment: The dates I have mentioned are taken from UNESCO website. If dating has many problems, then why believe Panini's 5th Century to be an accurate date? Why is that not a problem too? The point that must be highlighted is the following- there is a brazen attempt to fabricate history which doesnt exist. Every date which researchers inform us is contested when those dates dismiss the fabricated assumptions. And in the garb of difficulty of dating, imaginative history (a result of political propaganda) is then created, appropriating anything which Buddha or Buddhism does as part of Hindutva history.

Comment: Ruben's answer below perfectly brings out the small point I am making in more detail. Let us critically raise questions and investigate difficulties. But at the same time, let us not fall prey to political propaganda.

Comment: @HomagetoManjushri two things :1) if you are political about hindutva and history , then remember buddhism have many state sponsored religion at first and sri Lankan buddhists genocided hindus and have reservation, 2) you can't change my religious views (manu 12.95 , 12.96) still you couldn't answer the panini's astadhayyi part?

Comment: Yes I am aware of state sponsoring in Sri Lanka, the genocide of Indian Tamils, genocide conducted in Myanmar against Muslims, genocides in India in past against Buddhists and genocide being orchestrated currently in Gaza. All genocide is evil and we must put all efforts in preventing such atrocious acts done by people who claim to belong to this religion or that religion (or even no religion). Violence has no place in the world, especially in spirituality. And those who do it must be called out.

Comment: Also, factually you are incorrect. Buddhists are not given reservations anywhere. Further, I have no interest in changing your views, I merely wished to elucidate them. That helps to set the context of your question to all viewers. Regarding that I couldnt answer about Panini- I already did. I do it again-any date which does not agree with the Hindutva world view is deemed to be full of errors on account of difficulty of dating. However, any date given by the Hindutva ideology is beyond this difficulty of dating. WHY? This is not reason- this is agenda.

Answer (score 3):

According to Palikanon's page on [Alara Kalama](https://www.palikanon.com/english/pali_names/aa/aalara_kaalaama.htm):

> One of the two teachers to whom Gotama, after his renunciation, first
> attached himself, the other being Uddaka Rāmaputta. In the
> Milindapañha (p.236) Ālāra is mentioned as Gotama's fourth teacher.
> ....
>
> In the Ariyaparivesāna Sutta (M.i.163-5; also 240ff; ii.94ff, 212ff)
> the Buddha describes his visit to Ālāra. Gotama quickly mastered his
> doctrine and was able to repeat it by heart; but feeling sure that
> Ālāra not only knew the doctrine but had realised it, he approached
> him and questioned him about it. Ālāra then proclaimed the
> ākiñcaññāyatana (sphere of nothingness, see jhāna 7), and Gotama,
> putting forth energy and concentration greater than Ālāra's, made
> himself master of that state. Ālāra recognised his pupil's eminence
> and treated him as an equal, but Gotama, not having succeeded in his
> quest, took leave of Ālāra to go elsewhere (VibhA.432). When, after
> having practised austerities for six years, the Buddha attained
> Enlightenment and granted Sahampati's request to preach the doctrine,
> it was of Ālāra he thought first as being the fittest to hear the
> teaching. But Ālāra had died seven days earlier (Vin.i.7).
>
> As already stated above, the aim of Ālāra’s practices is stated to
> have been the attainment of Akiñcaññayatana, the stage of nothingness.
> Whether this statement is handed down with any real knowledge of the
> facts of his teaching, it is not now possible to say. **Asvaghosa, in
> his Buddhacarita (xii.17ff), puts into the mouth of Ārāda or Ālāra, a
> brief account of his philosophy. It has some resemblance - though this
> is slight - to the Sānkhya philosophy, but in Ālāra’s teaching some of
> the salient characteristics of the Sānkhya system are absent.** In
> reply to Gotama's questions about the religious life and the obtaining
> of final release, Ālāra describes a system of spiritual development
> which is identical with the methods of the Buddhist monk up to the
> last attainment but one. The monk reaches the four jhānas and then
> attains successively to the states of space, infinity and nothingness.
> The last three stages are described in the terms of the first three of
> the four Attainments.

From the above, we see that it was Asvaghosa who alleged, in his [Buddhacarita](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buddhacharita) (written a few centuries after the Buddha), that Alara Kalama taught something with some slight similarity to Samkhya. However, most of the salient characteristics of Samkhya is missing from Alara Kalama's teachings.

The Palikanon has this statement regarding [Sage Kapila](https://www.palikanon.com/english/pali_names/ka/kapila.htm), the founder of Samkhya:

> Kapila.-An ancient teacher of philosophy, mentioned together with
> Kanāda as having taught that the soul was limitless (na antavā)
> (UdA.339; see also Svetasvatara Upanisad v.2, and Rāmāyana i.40). He
> is probably identical with the founder of the Sānkhya system.

So, neither Sage Kapila nor Samkhya are mentioned in the Buddhist scriptures (Pali Canon), although he is mentioned in the Udana commentaries, along with Sage Kanada, as having taught that the soul was limitless, which is contradictory to what was taught by the Buddha. Udana is part of the Pali Canon in Khuddaka Nikaya, but the Udana commentaries are not.

It is interesting that suffering (dukkha), soteriological theories and some atheistic ideas are similar between Samkhya and Buddhism. However, the key ideas of Purusha and Prakrti of Samkhya is not at all found in Buddhism.

The wikipedia page on [Samkhya](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samkhya) talks of mutual influence between the earliest Samkhya ideas and, Buddhism and Jainism. However, Samkhya Karika definitely comes after the Buddha. The ideas of suffering and atheism in later Samkhya are said to come about due to influence by Buddhism, according to scholars.

> Buddhism and Jainism had developed in eastern India by the 5th century
> BCE. It is probable that these schools of thought and the earliest
> schools of Samkhya influenced each other. According to Burley, there
> is no evidence that a systematic samkhya-philosophy existed prior to
> the founding of Buddhism and Jainism, sometime in the 5th or 4th
> century BCE. A prominent similarity between Buddhism and Samkhya is
> the greater emphasis on suffering (dukkha) as the foundation for their
> respective soteriological theories, than other Indian
> philosophies. **However, suffering appears central to Samkhya in its
> later literature, which likely suggests a Buddhist influence.** Eliade,
> however, presents the alternate theory that Samkhya and Buddhism
> developed their soteriological theories over time, benefiting from
> their mutual influence.
>
> Larson, Bhattacharya and Potter state it to be likely that early
> Samkhya doctrines found in oldest Upanishads (~700-800 BCE) provided
> the contextual foundations and influenced **Buddhist and Jaina
> doctrines, and these became contemporaneous, sibling intellectual
> movements with Samkhya** and other schools of Hindu philosophy. This is
> evidenced, for example, by the references to Samkhya in ancient and
> medieval era Jaina literature.

And also:

> Chandradhar Sharma in 1960 affirmed that Samkhya in the beginning was
> based on the theistic absolute of Upanishads, but later on, **under the
> influence of Jaina and Buddhist thought**, it rejected theistic monism
> and was content with spiritualistic pluralism and atheistic realism.
> This also explains why some of the later Samkhya commentators, e.g.
> Vijnanabhiksu in the sixteenth century, tried to revive the earlier
> theism in Samkhya.

According to various  Wikipedia pages:

> The bulk of the Mahābhārata was probably compiled between the 3rd century BCE and the 3rd century CE, with the oldest preserved parts not much older than around 400 BCE.

> The Hinduism scholar Jeaneane Fowler, in her commentary on the (Bhagavad) Gita, considers second century BCE to be the probable date of composition. J. A. B. van Buitenen also states that the Gita was likely composed about 200 BCE. According to the Indologist Arvind Sharma, the Gita is generally accepted to be a 2nd-century-BCE text.

> Samkhya karika was probably composed sometime in the Gupta Empire period, between 320-540 CE

> The (Jataka) tales are dated between 300 BCE and 400 CE

> (Aṣṭādhyāyī) Authored by Sanskrit philologist and scholar Pāṇini and dated to around 500 BCE,

> (The historical Buddha's lifetime:) Most historians in the early 20th century use the earlier dates of 563 – 483 BCE

So, based on these, you can see that the Buddha lived centuries before Mahabharata, Bhagavad Gita, Samkhya Karika and Jataka Tales.

Meanwhile, Panini authored the Astadhyayi around the Buddha's lifetime. So, all texts composed in Classical Sanskrit obviously came after the Buddha's lifetime.

The only Hindu texts referenced in the Pali Canon are three of the Vedas.

The only other Hindu texts that existed before the Buddha's time are the Brhadaranyaka Upanishad and Chandogya Upanishad, although both are not named in the Pali Canon. All other Upanishads come after the Buddha. So, the only Hindu scriptures that could have influenced the Buddha are the three oldest Vedas and the two oldest Upanishads.

Answer (score 0):

According to Bhikhu sujato udaka ramaputta is rishi udalaks liniage.

https://discourse.suttacentral.net/t/a-ara-kalama-uddaka-ramaputta-what-tradition/6210/6

This liniage compiled chandogya upanishad. dialog with his son/swetaketu. he gave concept of atman, brahman.
They also compiled Brihadaranyaka . ( his name is aruni too.)

in DN 29, buddha explains why he was not satisfied with Udaka Ramaputtas teaching. Here he quotes famous non-duality teaching. "knowing one after which you dont need to know". by passaṃ na passatī’ti.

And in that sutta ,Buddhas argument against this philosophy is that, his teaching is only about path and not about the destination.

Teachers of that time were overly discussing about nibbana(the destination) and less about path. and hence he focused more on 8fold path and less on what is nibbana.